# Uncaught ReferenceError: init is not defined at onload

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, client, google-maps-markers

There is a similar question on here but it hasn't allowed me to solve my problem.  I'm creating a web page using the google maps javascript api.  I have made my own Restfull server with a route that the client will use to get map coords/data from my mysql database.

I'm able to load the map however i keep getting this error when its loaded into my browser after adding the makeRequest code to it.  The error i am currently getting is ***Uncaught ReferenceError: init is not defined
    at onload***

I believe its refering to body onload="init();" in my HTML.

Here is my code, any assistance would be greatly appreciated as my JS knowledge is somewhat limited. Thank you in advance

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Team Locations</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        body {
            font: normal 14px Verdana;
        }

        h1 {
            font-size: 24px;
        }

        h2 {
            font-size: 18px;
        }

        #sidebar {
            float: right;
            width: 30%;
        }

        #main {
            padding-right: 15px;
        }

        .infoWindow {
            width: 220px;
        }

    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDNMFE1XBzVnhPOI5IH90FrwumFfLo5x40&callback=initMap"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        //<![CDATA[

        var map;

        // Centre of York
        var center = new google.maps.LatLng(53.957741, -1.082260);

        var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

        function init() {

            var mapOptions = {
                zoom: 13,
                center: center,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            }

            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);


            makeRequest('http://localhost:5032/', function(data) {

                    var data = JSON.parse(data.responseText);

                    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                        displayLocation(data[i]);
                    });
            },

                function makeRequest(url, callback) {
                    var request;
                    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
                        request = new XMLHttpRequest(); // IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
                    } else {
                        request = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP"); // IE6, IE5
                    }
                    request.onreadystatechange = function() {
                        if (request.readyState == 4 && request.status == 200) {
                            callback(request);
                        }
                    }
                    request.open("GET", url, true);
                    request.send();
                }
            });




            //]]>

    </script>
</head>

<body onload="init();">

    <h1>Team Locations</h1>

    <section id="sidebar">
        <div id="directions_panel"></div>
    </section>

    <section id="main">
        <div id="map_canvas" style="width: 70%; height: 500px;"></div>
    </section>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: See my main comment but you also have this warning in the console, this is the hint. `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ')'`

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `init()` on render and not on load.

Try passing the reference of the function.

```
<body onload="init">
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple syntax issue. Your init function ends with a comma `,` and you have an additional `});` at the end of the code, so it looks like you copied some code from an object patterm but missed either the opening `({` or you need to delete that closing `})` and the comma after the `init()` function.

Comment: Thank you, I’ll check that out

Answer (score 0):

Remove the comma and add one more brace to init() as below:

suggestion : copy & replace your init() with the below code.

```
    function init() {

        var mapOptions = {
            zoom: 13,
            center: center,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        }

        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);


        makeRequest('http://localhost:5032/', function(data) {

                var data = JSON.parse(data.responseText);

                for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                    displayLocation(data[i]);
                });
        }
}
```